# Foreach and nth terms

Tags: php

I'm trying to print content into three columns meaning for the first column I need to retrieve records matching the term 3n-2. How would I do so... using modulus maybe? Thank you!

```
foreach($grid as $tile):
    echo '<div class="tile"><img src="/media/full/' . $tile['source'] . '"/></div>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: What do you mean with: `term 3n-2` ?

Comment: It would be helpful to know more about the HTML/CSS.

Comment: @Rizier123 I'm retrieving records from MySQL. In the first column, I'd like to show records 1,4,7 etc.

Comment: Using modulus, yes. Have you tried?

Comment: `foreach($grid as $key => $tile): if (($key % 3) == 1) {...}`

Comment: @spudmonkee I hope my answer helps and you are looking for something like this.

Comment: i will suggest you to do it in database in the `select` query ...`where id%3=1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is just an additional counter:

```
$i=0;
foreach($grid as $tile) {
    if($i++ % 3 == 0) {
        //do something every 3rd time
    }
    //do something every time
}
```

Comment: Increment it somewhere).

Comment: add `$i++` within the loop.

Comment: Also, you are using some strange mix syntaxes in your OP.

Comment: Yes, I was too quick there, sorry. Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I haven't seen this compact notation before. Interesting what PHP allows, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Alex, yes. Very convenient. But note that there is even a subtle difference between `$i++` and `++$i`. Check the documentation and behold the great powers of PHP! :)  (although this syntax is shared with C++, Java(Script) and others).

Answer (score 1):

I think you look for something like this:

(Example code, just change `$arr` with `$grid`)

```
<?php

    $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

    for($count = 0; $count < count($arr); $count++) {

        if($count % 3 == 0 && $count != 0)
            echo "<br />";
        echo    $arr[$count];

    }


?>
```

Output:

```
123
456
789
```

Or if you want the columns in separate arrays:

```
<?php

    $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    $columnOne = array();
    $columnTwo = array();
    $columnThree = array();

    for($count = 0; $count < count($arr); $count++) {

        if($count % 3 == 0)
            $columnOne[] = $arr[$count];
        elseif($count % 3 == 1)
            $columnTwo[] = $arr[$count];
        else
            $columnThree[] = $arr[$count];

    }

    print_r($columnOne);
    print_r($columnTwo);
    print_r($columnThree);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 [2] => 7 )
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 [2] => 8 )
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 6 [2] => 9 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would use modulus php operator `%`, if I correctly understand what you mean:

```
<?php
  $grid = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7); # just for testing

  $n = 1;
  foreach($grid as $tile) {
    if (($n + 2) % 3 == 0) {
      #echo '<div class="tile"><img src="/media/full/' . $tile['source'] . '"/></div>';
      echo "$n\n"; # just for testing
    }
    $n++;
  }
?>
```

Which produces:

```
$ php x.php 
1
4
7
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach can also give you the index and like you already suggested you can pick the rows you want with an IF or you can do a negative IF and use `continue;` to skip what you don't want.

```
foreach($grid as $i => $tile):
    if ($i % 3 == 2):
```